# h1 massive "margin", unessesarry whitespace

Tags: css

Looked into some different questions and In my example I'l use all of them to show you it's still not working for my part, here is an Image:

[image]

What I've added as many questions suggest

```
h1{
line-height:2px;
margin:auto;
padding:0;
font-size:10px;
}
```

Still as you can see got the same issue.

If I use `margin:0;` it still takes space:
[image]

Here is a fiddle if you want to see it for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/h6zkyj7q/

What I'm trying to acheive is lower the first images margin by half

Comment: don't give line height

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: wait my bad , that's wrong....something is over writing `margin:0` in `h1`, btw in the fiddle i don't get any margin , if you still want 0 padding as well then `display:inline` should help you , but's if that helps you then there is no point of using `h1` to begin with

Comment: Man. your code has an architectural problem. My suggestion is to plan you markup first. Think about the meaning of each part and divide it in blocks.

Comment: @RicardoFerreira Like what "architectural problem"?

Comment: The problem raises in relation to the flex behavior inherited from the parent

Comment: I mean in your markup and style.  you are mixing positions with display techniques and this is resulting on that. I will show you in an example.

Comment: Here is my example. https://jsfiddle.net/ricardoferreirades/dLfnqxer/21/ .
Please, have a look. I divided your component  in 4 blocks and I only add styles for the things html cannot do for me automatically. Try to get the advantage of the HTML before start to  add styles. And when styles are needed, try to think firs about the expectation, than you will figure out the solution as faster as possible. Keep focused. I hope I helped somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem here is the box model layout altered by the use of `flex` and specific the altered behavior from the property [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) which basically from their **normal** default value will make your elements have that "stretch" behavior. To solve it you can alter that property and avoid your elements from stretch to the full parent container.

[Modified JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8v50ytgp/)

---

- Also you need to reset the margin fully with `0`

Comment: the fiddle looks the same to me, im afraid

Comment: ..... did you inspect it ? it solves the mistery .... of your h1 taking that space but you can see that property is the one to allow you center the items better, nevermind don't try to understand deeply the reasons of your problem and learn just look forward to the easiest solution without known why it was wrong

Comment: it actually does go away, but why is not the p tag going up with it?

Comment: guess your answer is more correct to my question, thanks for your answer:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the styles of your `h1`. It's, as one of the commenters said, originating from the container styles:

```css
#boka {
  /* ... */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

There's no point in using a flexbox in your current setup, and especially, be careful of using `flex-wrap: wrap`.

So, to solve the problem, you could remove flexbox styles from your container, make your `h1` centered and you'll get the same result.

Answer (score -3):

I think that's the default margin of H1, you can try use h4 or h3.

Cheers

Comment: did you try it yourself before answering? https://prnt.sc/snjb04

Comment: Yep,, but maybe you can try like this #boka{
width: 400px;
height: 50%;
top:30%;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: rgba(200,214,196,0.8);
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
/*display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;*/
justify-content: center;
}

h1{
  line-height:2px;
margin:auto;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
}
p{
  padding: 10px
}